# ¿Por qué este wrapper de js no funciona?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

Holaa, os explico lo que estoy haciendo: 
Estoy haciendo un menu wrapper, y quiero que cuando se presione el botón de ocultar se le guarde en el DOM Storage un value y dependiendo de ese value el menú wrapper se le aplique una variable o se la elimine.

El problema es que no se ejecuta de forma correcta el código ocasionando que solamente se le añada la clase y no se la elimine.

Dejo aquí el código.

HTML:

```
<div class="root-panel">
<div class="tres-lines" id="hide" onclick="a()">
```

CSS:

```
.contract{
width: 7%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
 function a() {


            //$('.root-panel').addClass('contract');
            const asd = "1";

            const operario = parseInt(asd) + 1;
            localStorage.setItem('dost', operario);
            setInterval("var cde = localStorage.getItem('dost')", 100);
            setTimeout("console.log(cde)", 1000);

     
            /*  Detector de si ha presionado el botón para contraer el menú */

            setInterval(function () {
                if (cde < 2) {
                    $('.root-panel').removeClass('contract');
                }
                else {
                    $('.root-panel').addClass('contract');
                }


            }, 100);


        
            setTimeout(function () {


                if (cde === 2) {
                    const supra_operador = parseInt(cde) - 1;
                    localStorage.setItem('dost', supra_operador);
                    console.log(cde);
                    if (cde < 2) {
                        $('.root-panel').removeClass('contract');
                        console.log('de');
                    }

                }


            }, 1000);

        



        }
```

Comment: Algún error en la consola del navegador? Qué es `cde`?

Comment: @Alfabravo Hola, no, no arroja ningún error.
Cde es la variable que obtiene le valor 'dost' del localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado por mi propia cuenta.
Aquí dejo el code por si a alguien le sirve.

JS:

```
    const asd = "1";
    localStorage.setItem('secure', asd);
    const preload = localStorage.getItem('secure');
    const operario = parseInt(asd) + parseInt(preload);
    localStorage.setItem('dost', operario);
    setInterval("var gade = localStorage.getItem('dost')", 100);

    function a() {


        //$('.root-panel').addClass('contract');

        
        console.log(gade);

 
        /*  Detector de si ha presionado el botón para contraer el menú */

      
            if (gade < 2) {
                $('.root-panel').removeClass('contract');
            }
            else {
                $('.root-panel').addClass('contract');
            }


      


    
        

      

    
            if (gade === "2") {
                const supra_operador = parseInt(gade) - 1;

                localStorage.setItem('dost', supra_operador);

                console.log(gade);

            }

            

     
    
        if (gade < 2) {
            $('.root-panel').removeClass('contract');
            console.log('de');
        }



        if (gade == "1") {
            const second_operario = parseInt(preload) + 1;
            localStorage.setItem('dost', second_operario);
        }


    }
```